# How to change height of Xamarin Shell.TitleView?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I cannot find a way to customize the height parameter of Shell.TitleView

Comment: It's because as of now there is no way to change the height of Navigation Bar in Xamarin.Forms. See the issue https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7256

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 3):

you could try to add `android:actionBarSize` to your `styles.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     ...

    <!-- ********* CHECK HERE ********* -->
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">80dp</item>

    ...
  </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: If using the above code the app wont deploy. Reason being is the units used 'dp' are incorrect, it should be 'dip'

Answer (score 0):

I had put the stacklayout below navigationbar with same backgroundColor as Navigationbar. Than put controls in that stacklayout. It seems to user as Navigation bar height is increased.

Comment: I've already done so, but shell.title has this shadow just below title hence space between title and stacklayout below is visible. Unfortunatelly I also cannot turn this shadow off

Comment: use <item name="elevation">0dp</item> in styles.xml to remove shadow. But you may hit another  bug https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7337.