# Xamarin Forms Scaling Components with font size

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is it possible to scale labels, buttons, and frames with font size? I'm running into `accessibility` issues, where `iOS` has a few lines to disable all accessibility scaling and after googling android doesn't seem to have it at all. I have a number of components that have text inside and buttons that have custom fonts for `arrows` `pause` and `play` icons which are custom fonts. I need to scale the entire button around depending if the font size within the accessibility has been changed.

**Only for iOS**: [Accessibility Scaling for Named Font Sizes on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/named-font-size-scaling), cannot find anything about android.

Another post: [Getting Android/iOS Accessibility font sizes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f76a6d36-40e5-4ec8-90c8-7b24e19fcd31/getting-androidios-accessibility-font-sizes?forum=xamarincrossplatform), first answer has this line of code for android `Android.Content.Res.Resources.System.Configuration.FontScale` but I can't seem to be able to access the `Android.Content` anywhere I try to use it.

Many Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** [Temp Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290757/prevent-system-fontsize-change-from-affecting-the-size-in-the-xamarin-applicatio#:%7E:text=SImply%20add%20this%20in%20your%20MainActivity%20after%20OnCreate.). Still would like to know if its even possible to do component scaling with fontsize.

[image]

**Reference**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BugTestMediaElement.Page3">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Frame BackgroundColor="White"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label Text="Test"
                       FontSize="{StaticResource ToolbarIconFontSize}"
                       TextColor="Black" />
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: AFAIK, AppShell lacks cross-platform way to scale height of TitleView. Might be worth opening an Accessibility issue at `github maui issues`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following approach. In `App.xaml` file (application wide declarations), I make the following declarations:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <OnPlatform x:Key="ToolbarIconFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="48" iOS="64" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then on a page (I use icons from FontAwesome), I make this declaration:

```xml
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridTitle}" RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*, 0.20*, 0.20*">

       <!-- other declarations are skipped -->

       <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" Command="{Binding SomeActionCommand}">
                <ImageButton.Source>
                    <FontImageSource Glyph="{x:Static icons:IconFontGlyphNames.SomeActionSymbol}" 
                                     FontFamily="IconFontFamily" 
                                     Color="White" 
                                     Size="{StaticResource ToolbarIconFontSize}" />                    
                </ImageButton.Source>
       </ImageButton>

       <!-- other declarations are skipped -->

    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

IconFontGlyphNames class declarations look like that:

```cs
public static class IconFontGlyphNames
{
    public const string SomeActionSymbol = "\uf234";

    // other declarations are skipped
}
```

I set fonts sizes for icons, and texts using this approach, and it works fine as for Android and for iOS platform.

---

Update #1. Explaining `Shell.TitleView` location.

`Shell.TitleView` is located here:

```xml
<ContentPage>

   <Shell.TitleView>
      <!-- Shell title view elements go here -->
   </Shell.TitleView>

   <ContentPage.Content>
      <!-- Your page body elements go here -->
   </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I'm trying this out in a test project and I cant seem to get anything to display on the screen by wrapping a `StackLayout` with `Shell.TitleView`. Am I missing something from your explanation?

Comment: `Shell.TitleView` cannot be inside of `StackLayout`. It is top-level element. Its is nested just in `ContentPage` element.

Comment: It is outside `StackLayout` thats why I'm confused.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist I've updated my answer, please check and let me know how it is going on your side.

Comment: Please refer to my edited post. I've added the code I'm using. I get nothing on display.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist In my application (it has set toolbar color to green in platform based project), this xaml look like that: https://i.imgur.com/ttlfcJZ.png

Please correct me if I am wrong. Did you expect to get `Shell.TitleView` height increased ? If so, it can be done [in platform-based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443279/how-to-change-height-of-xamarin-shell-titleview), not in the platform-agnostic project.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I think for now I will just disable the Accessibility scaling and add my own custom one as an in-game option. This way it will never break the game sizing. As currently there is no support for Accessibility.